# CS50X Readability - Issue with only one output

Tags: c

There's a wrong output of the tests.

Literally, every test is passing except for one where the output should be Grade 8 instead of Grade 7.

I tried debugging and the text that is not passing is:

> When he was nearly thirteen, my brother Jem got his arm badly broken at the elbow. When it healed, and Jem's fears of never being able to play football were assuaged, he was seldom self-conscious about his injury. His left arm was somewhat shorter than his right; when he stood or walked, the back of his hand was at right angles to his body, his thumb parallel to his thigh.

And after debugging, I see that what's changing the grade result is the last dot of the entire text.

If I do send the text without the final dot, it will do Grade 8 as it is expected. But if I write the dot, it's just going to be Grade 7.

My code is:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <math.h>
// Prototypes
int count_letters(string text);
int count_words(string text);
int count_sentences(string text);

int main(void)
{
    // Prompt the user for the text string.
    string userInput = get_string("Text: ");
    float l = count_letters(userInput);
    float w = count_words(userInput);
    float s = count_sentences(userInput);
    float lResult = ((float)l*100) / (float)w;
    float sResult = ((float)s*100) / (float)w;
    // float lResult = l / w * 100;
    // float sResult = s / w * 100;
    float index = 0.0588 * lResult - 0.296 * sResult - 15.8;
    int roundedIndex = round(index);


    if (roundedIndex <= 0)
    {
        printf("Before Grade 1\n");
    }
    else if (roundedIndex >= 16)
    {
        printf("Grade 16+\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Grade %d\n", roundedIndex);
    }
    return 0;

}
// Count characters.
int count_letters(string text)
{
    // Storage the letters count.
    int lettersCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; text[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(text[i])){
            lettersCount++;
        }
    }
    return lettersCount;
}

int count_words(string text)
{
    int wordsCount = 0;
    int ifWord = 0;

    for(int i = 0; text[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (isalpha(text[i]) || text[i] == '\'')
        {
            if (!ifWord)
            {
                ifWord = 1;
                wordsCount++;
            }
        }
        else {
            ifWord = 0;
        }
    }
    return wordsCount;
}

int count_sentences(string text)
{
    int sentenceCount = 0;

    for (int i = 0; text[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        char c = text[i];
        if (c == '.' || c == '?' || c == '!') {
            sentenceCount++;
        }
    }
    return sentenceCount;
}
```

I've tried so many things that I do not know what else to try anymore.

Comment: Have you considered that "self-conscious" is ONE _compound_ word? Welcome to coding... Just when you think you've found the problem, it turns out to be something else...

Comment: @Fe2O3 Thank you for that. How did you come to that conclusion? I'm new to coding, and I'm not worried about failing but not learning how to solve the issues. Experience? I'm also a non-native speaker so maybe skipped that unintentionally.

Comment: How? Your experience and suggestion about the trailing 'period' didn't make sense to me. I saw that you accounted for the apostrophe in "Jem's", so I went looking for something else that might make one word appear to be two. (More words with the same number of letters implies a lower reading level. Think of Dr. Suess books.) Glad you're moving forward!

Comment: @Fe2O3 Thank you. I did move forward and that was the final step into sending the submit.

I did not catch the apostrophe because of "Jem's" but rather, before going deep in developing, I caught the apostrophe in the word "You're", which was counting two words instead of only one in previous examples.

I'm new to coding, maybe it has to be something like coding awareness. Just like a semi colon can mess up with a few things, so can happen if you don't pay enough attention. 

Thanks again!

Comment: There are two types of programmers: those who have had problems caused by not taking edge cases into account, and liars.

Comment: @CiMoran, Aside:  Rarely is `float` the best floating point type to use.  Instead use `double` and save `float` for cases where `float` is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently, you only increase your word count *the next time* you see an alpha character or an apostrophe, after having *not* previously seen one (the initial state). As pointed out in the comments, there are more edge cases to consider to form a valid *word*, such as a hyphen character.

---

Note that, for the purpose of this exercise, the number of *words* can simply be counted as the number of spaces plus one.

That is,

```
int count_words(string text)
{
    int wordsCount = 1;

    for(int i = 0; text[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (text[i] == ' ')
        {   
            wordsCount++;
        }   
    }

    return wordsCount;
}
```